# Collapse certain group jqGrid

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I am using **jqGrid-4.4.1** with grouping columns.

I am well aware with grouping options at [jqGrid documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3agrouping)

```
....
groupingView: { 
              groupField: ['Group'],
              groupColumnShow: [false],
              groupCollapse: true

},
....
```

But, this collapses all groups in the table. I want to collapse only few groups not all.

Let say I have 3 groups in the table. Then I do want to collapse only 1 of it rest other should be open.

Is it possible ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not aware of any configuration parameters which allow for individual group configuration, but one possible solution would be to start with the grid un-grouped, and then collapse the desired group using :

```
jQuery(tableName).jqGrid('groupingToggle',groupHeading);
```

once the data has loaded.

If you visit the [demo page](http://www.trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html), click "Grouping" heading, and then "Simple grouping with array data", you can toggle the third group with :

```
jQuery('#list48').jqGrid('groupingToggle','list48ghead_0_2')
```

for example.